# How can i calculate the SUM of various cells within a COUNTIFS?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a database in excel where columns hold lots of different pieces of data. On a different sheet I would like to be able to perform a `SUM` within a `COUNTIFS` statement.

The logic in my head is this, but obviously it does not work:

```
=COUNTIFS($B:$B,$F4,(SUM($C:$C+$D:$D)),">=2")
```

So here I am saying if in column B of the database the value is equal to what I have in cell F4 on my sheet, then I would like, for each row where the value is what I have in F4, to add up the values between cells C and D, and if that value is greater than 2 then count it, if not then do not count it.

Here is a picture of expected output:

[image: "expected output"]

Comment: Two `SUMIF` added together maybe? > `=SUMIF(DATABASE!F:F,C3,DATABASE!H:H)+SUMIF(DATABASE!F:F,C3,DATABASE!I:I)`. Or rather use referenced parts of the whole columns.

Comment: On you database sheet, you could make another column that is just `IF(H+I >= 2, H+I, 0)`, let's say this ended up in col `Z`. then your formula is `=SUMIF(DATABASE!F:F, $C$3, DATABASE!Z:Z)`. Or make col `Z` `=H+I` and then use `SUMIFS` (instead of `SUMIF`, notice the extra `S` at the end) with the extra `">=2` condition on `DATABASE!Z:Z`

Comment: I have updated the post as what you have suggested won't work because i need to do is to count only if the sum of those columns is greater than 2

Comment: At the moment the work around i have is indeed to just add the two columns on the Database sheet, however the sheet i have will change all the time, it will grow so i dont want to have to keep adding formulae to the database sheet

Comment: How about share some sample data and expected output?

Comment: @user3672422 but it's a formula so it doesn't matter if your sheet changes? Especially if you use [a table](https://exceljet.net/excel-tables) for your "database" as this will grow the formula as you add new data and is almost no effort on your part. Another slightly more complicated but ultimately better solution is not to keep you "database" on a worksheet but rather store it in the [datamodel](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/create-a-data-model-in-excel-87e7a54c-87dc-488e-9410-5c75dbcb0f7b) which is the modern way to use Excel and totally worth your time learning how to use.

Comment: I have attached a photo to show expected output

Comment: I'm sorry but your expected output makes 0 sense at this moment to me. Why is ham >=3 result 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option based on your sample data, however by the looks of it I get different results than yours:

[image]

**Formula** in `G4`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$4:$B$12=$F4)*($C$4:$C$12+$D$4:$D$12>=G$3))
```

> ***Note:*** I changed cell's `G3:H3` value to be able to reference them.

Drag down and right. For a dynamic reference style you might try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((F2:INDEX(F:F,COUNTA(F:F))=C3)*(H2:INDEX(H:H,COUNTA(H:H))+I2:INDEX(I:I,COUNTA(I:I))>=2))
```

Comment: I have taken your code to try and adapt it to my sheet. i get a #VALUE error. =SUMPRODUCT((DATABASE!$F:$F=$C4)*(DATABASE!$H:$H+DATABASE!$I:$I>=2)). The sheet where the data is held is called DATABASE

Comment: I dont want to reference specific rows, i want it to look completely down the column.

Comment: @user3672422, glad to have helped mate :S.....either way, stay away from whole column references. Instead try implement some `INDEX`

Comment: @user3672422, just note you get the `#VALUE` error exactly because you reference a whole column. You probably have string values in some row in those columns. What would you expect when you add string values to eachother? Hence again, don't reference whole columns

Comment: I see. And of course when i reference the cells range that contain data i obviously get no error. Is there anyway then find the last row and set that as the range? =SUMPRODUCT((DATABASE!$F2:$Flastrow=$C4)*(DATABASE!$H2:$Hlastrow+DATABASE!$I2:$Ilastrow>=2)). I will be adding to the rows all the time hence the question... Many thanks for your continued help

Comment: @user3672422, yes you'll have to add in Index as mentioned. If I got time I'll try to edit my answer

Comment: @user3672422, i see you opening new questions. Which makes me wonder if this particular question has now been answered and can be closed.

Comment: It has been closed

Answer (score 0):

Using your layout

Using a helper column in column E

`=C4+D4`

Then drag that down

Putting this formula in G4 and dragging down should do what you want

```
=COUNTIFS(E:E;$G$3;B:B;F4)
```

and this in H4

```
=COUNTIFS(E:E;$H$3;B:B;F4)
```

As someone else pointed out, your sample expected result is incorrect if I understand what it is that you want to achieve correctly. You can change the Value in G3 and H3 respectively to adjust your criteria if necessary. In my test i had >=2 and >=3 respectively